# generate textview with shape drawable dynamically inside the listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I would like to ask how to create textview inside listview items with custom adapter and put onclick event on each textview generated. I want to achieve the image attached.

[image]
I was able to do it manually in XML but i want to generate it dynamically:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView;
    if (convertView != null) {
        itemView = convertView;
    }else {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.challenges, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    final TextView mondayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.monday);
    TextView tuesdayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
    TextView wednesdayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
    TextView thursdayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thursday);
    TextView fridayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.friday);
    TextView saturdayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.saturday);
    TextView sundayTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sunday);



    Items itm = itemList.get(position);

    mondayTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Clicked");
            itm.setSelected(1);
            SelectedAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mondayTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_view_pink);
            mondayTxt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });

    //other click event for other text

    txtTitle.setText(itm.getName());

    if(itm.getSelected() != null && itm.getSelected() != 0){
        mondayTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_view);
        mondayTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    return itemView;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
My goal is when i clicked the mondatTxt iside the item listview the background of the text will change to **R.drawable.circle_view_pink** while other that is not currently click will still be normal text which ic **R.drawable.circle_view**.
The problem on the adapter is when i clicked monday textview it will also reflected to other textview.

Thanks.

Comment: and why you want to do it from java?

Comment: i would like to set an id each textview and put onclick event on it depending on the id of listview items

Comment: why do you need a `ShapeDrawable`? your shape is not complex one, you can make it in pure xml

Comment: Why do you want to create this inside a `TextView`? It is possible using an `ImageSpan`, but it would be easier to create a custom `View` or `ImageView` subclass IMO. Also, there are several libraries that create circular `ImageView`s with the option of text content, i.e.: https://github.com/pavlospt/CircleView

Comment: i can put the shape as background like mTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_view); just need to generate the text view and make it aligned like on the attached

Comment: you already created 7 `TextViews`, just wrap them inside `LinearLayout`

Comment: Yes, but i would like to generate it dynamically using java code.

Comment: LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); TextView tv = new TextView(this); ll.addView(tv)

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

for your update question:

replace this code

```
if(itm.getSelected() != null && itm.getSelected() != 0){
    mondayTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_view);
    mondayTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

with

```
if(itm.getSelected() != null && itm.getSelected() != 0){
    // not select
    mondayTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_view);
    mondayTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}else{
    // select
    mondayTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_view_pink);
    mondayTxt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

You need update the selected item in getView.
and what's your Items.getSelected() return ? int ? but why check whether selected is null or not?

Comment: when i click the mondayTxt it get the last item in the row instead of the current

Comment: if 1 is select, why you check ```item.getSelected() != 0```?